# Flutter Nested Navigation Back Button handling on Android

Tags: android, flutter, routes

##### Background

I have a Navigator widget on my `InitialPage` and I am pushing two routes ontop of it (`NestedFirstRoute` and `NestedSecondRoute`). When I press the physical back button on Android, Both the routes in Navigator are popped (which is expected).

##### Use case

So I would like to handle this case when the back button is pressed only the top route (`NestedSecondRoute`) must be popped.

#### Solution I tried

To deal with this issue I have wrapped the Navigator widget in [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to handle the back button press events and assigned keys to nested routes so as to use them when popping routes in the willPop scope.

I get an exception on this line

> if (NestedFirstPage.firstPageKey.currentState!.canPop()) {

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

Heres the minimal and complete code sample

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case NestedFirstPage.route:
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: () async {
                    if (NestedFirstPage.firstPageKey.currentState!.canPop()) {
                      NestedFirstPage.firstPageKey.currentState!.pop();
                      return false;
                    } else if (NestedSecondPage.secondPageKey.currentState!
                        .canPop()) {
                      NestedSecondPage.secondPageKey.currentState!.pop();
                      return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                  },
                  child: Navigator(
                    key: _navigatorKey,
                    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                      switch (settings.name) {
                        case Navigator.defaultRouteName:
                          return MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const NestedFirstPage(),
                            settings: settings,
                          );
                        case NestedSecondPage.route:
                          return MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const NestedSecondPage(),
                            settings: settings,
                          );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              settings: settings,
            );
        }
      },
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const InitialPage(title: 'Initial Page'),
    );
  }
}

class InitialPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitialPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, NestedFirstPage.route);
              },
              child: const Text('Move to Nested First Page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NestedFirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedFirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> firstPageKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static const String route = '/nested/first';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: firstPageKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Nested First Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('First page'),
            OutlinedButton(
              child: const Text('Move to Nested Second Page'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, NestedSecondPage.route);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NestedSecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedSecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> secondPageKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static const String route = '/nested/second';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: secondPageKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Nested Second Page')),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i think your NestedFirstPage.firstPageKey.currentState is null, try print the value. And find where the the value must set

Comment: There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14083#issuecomment-758809587) which is sadly closed, where people discussed workarounds. One of them is the [flow_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flow_builder) package. It may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of the above code which will allow pushing nested routes and can be popped via android back button

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        routes: {
          '/nested/first': (context) => const NestedFirstPage(),
          '/nested/first/second': (context) => const NestedSecondPage()
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const RouteManager());
  }
}

class InitialPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitialPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  static const String route = '/';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (navigatorKey.currentState != null &&
            navigatorKey.currentState!.canPop()) {
          navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  navigate(context, NestedFirstPage.route);
                },
                child: const Text('Move to Nested First Page'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> navigate(BuildContext context, String route,
        {bool isDialog = false, bool isRootNavigator = true}) =>
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: isRootNavigator).pushNamed(route);

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class RouteManager extends StatelessWidget {
  const RouteManager({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
        key: navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/nested/first':
              builder = (BuildContext _) => const NestedFirstPage();
              break;
            case '/nested/first/second':
              builder = (BuildContext _) => const NestedSecondPage();
              break;
            default:
              builder =
                  (BuildContext _) => const InitialPage(title: 'Initial Page');
          }
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
        });
  }
}

class NestedFirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> firstPageKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static const String route = '/nested/first';

  const NestedFirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: firstPageKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Nested First Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('First page'),
            OutlinedButton(
              child: const Text('Move to Nested Second Page'),
              onPressed: () {
                navigate(context, NestedSecondPage.route);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NestedSecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedSecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> secondPageKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static const String route = '/nested/first/second';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: secondPageKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Nested Second Page')),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Heres a [real world example](https://gist.github.com/maheshmnj/894922ccb67f5fdc4ffb652e41916fa2) with a Nested BottomNavigationbar.

Comment: You are doing the opposite of what's asked, then answer is:

        if (navigatorKey.currentState != null &&
            navigatorKey.currentState!.canPop()) {
          navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
In the onWillPop method

Comment: @Prateek I wanted to pop the nested route (not all the routes), so I am returning true only if the condition satisfies and false otherwise.  So this is intended, You may verify this by running the code sample on a Android device.